# Python: How do I get a new value every instance in a np.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a data set with a column filled with 1s and 0s as such:

```
column 1:
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
1
```

and I am currently using np.where() to create a new column that segments the data from column 1.
The issue is, whenever it comes across a new segments of 1s I want the values in column 2 to increase by 1.

```
n = 1
df['column2'] = np.where(df['column1'] == 1 ,  n + 1  , 0)
```

The results I am getting:

```
column 1: column 2:
1            1
1            1
1            1
1            1
0            0
0            0
0            0 
1            1
1            1
0            0
1            1
1            1
```

what I am trying to achieve

```
column 1: column 2:
1            1
1            1
1            1
1            1
0            0
0            0
0            0 
1            2
1            2
0            0
1            3
1            3
```

Comment: There's no automatic way to do that.  You will need to use `apply` and have your own function track that.  You can remember the states with globals.

Comment: There are vectorized ways to do this, e.g. groups and cumsums. Are you _required_ to only use `np.where` or you only asked for `np.where` because that's what you used so far?

Comment: How does Apply work?

Comment: No, np.where is just the only one I am familar with. I am open to new ideas!

Comment: `np.where` is NOT an iterator; that is, it does not operate on one row, and then go on to the next.  The 3 arguments are evaluated in full, and then passed to the Python function.  `df['column1'] == 1` ,  `n + 1 ` , `0`, are a `Series`, and 2 numbers.  There seems to be some sort of pandas folklore that leads people to assume `np.where` is drop-in replacement for the row by row iteration of `apply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheeky one-liner:

```
df["column2"] = df['column1'].diff().ne(0).cumsum().add(1).floordiv(2).where(df['column1'].astype(bool), other=0)
```

df:

```
    column1  column2
0         1        1
1         1        1
2         1        1
3         1        1
4         0        0
5         0        0
6         0        0
7         1        2
8         1        2
9         0        0
10        1        3
11        1        3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this also:

```
df['column 2:'] = (df.assign(grp = (df['column 1:'].diff() != 0).cumsum())
                     .where(df['column 1:'].astype(bool))
                     .groupby('grp').ngroup().add(1).fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
    column 1:  column 2:
0           1        1.0
1           1        1.0
2           1        1.0
3           1        1.0
4           0        0.0
5           0        0.0
6           0        0.0
7           1        2.0
8           1        2.0
9           0        0.0
10          1        3.0
11          1        3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

A vectorial solution without `groupby`, just incrementing the value whenever there is a 0->1 transition:

```
df['column2'] = (df['column1'].diff().eq(1).cumsum()
                 .add(df['column1'].iloc[0]).mul(df['column1'])
                 )
```

Alternative:

```
df['column2'] = (df['column1'].sub(df['column1'].shift(fill_value=0))
                 .eq(1).cumsum().mul(df['column1'])
                 )
```

Output:

```
    column1  column2
0         1        1
1         1        1
2         1        1
3         1        1
4         0        0
5         0        0
6         0        0
7         1        2
8         1        2
9         0        0
10        1        3
11        1        3
```

##### intermediates

option 1:

```
    column1  column2  diff  eq(1)  cumsum  add_first  mul(df['column1'])
0         1        1   NaN  False       0          1                   1
1         1        1   0.0  False       0          1                   1
2         1        1   0.0  False       0          1                   1
3         1        1   0.0  False       0          1                   1
4         0        0  -1.0  False       0          1                   0
5         0        0   0.0  False       0          1                   0
6         0        0   0.0  False       0          1                   0
7         1        2   1.0   True       1          2                   2
8         1        2   0.0  False       1          2                   2
9         0        0  -1.0  False       1          2                   0
10        1        3   1.0   True       2          3                   3
11        1        3   0.0  False       2          3                   3
```

option 2:

```
    column1  column2  diff  eq(1)  cumsum  mul(df['column1'])
0         1        1     1   True       1                   1
1         1        1     0  False       1                   0
2         1        1     0  False       1                   0
3         1        1     0  False       1                   0
4         0        0    -1  False       1                   0
5         0        0     0  False       1                   0
6         0        0     0  False       1                   0
7         1        2     1   True       2                   1
8         1        2     0  False       2                   0
9         0        0    -1  False       2                   0
10        1        3     1   True       3                   1
11        1        3     0  False       3                   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with `apply`.  Note that I track both 0s and 1s because I misread the problem originally.  The `last and...` means that a 0 will return 0.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [ [1], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [1], [1], ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['data'])

track = [0,0]
last = -1
def countthem(val):
    global last
    if val != last:
        track[val] += 1
        last = val
    return last and track[last]

df['column2'] = df['data'].apply(countthem)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    data  column2
0      1        1
1      1        1
2      1        1
3      1        1
4      0        0
5      0        0
6      0        0
7      1        2
8      1        2
9      0        0
10     1        3
11     1        3
```